# How to the get wildcard path variable in the controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-reactor

I have a controller:

```
@PostMapping("/name/**")
public Mono<String> doSomething(HttpEntity<byte[]> requestEntity,
                                ServerHttpRequest serverHttpRequest) {
    String restOfTheUrl = //the ** part is what i need here
    return webClient.forwardRequest(requestEntity, serviceUrl + "/" +     restOfTheUrl);
}
```

How do I obtain the URL string (including all query params) thats after the `/name/` ?? basically I need the `**` part. Of course I can remove the `/name/` from `serverHttpRequest.getPath(..)` but is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@PostMapping("/name/{*path}")
public Mono<String> doSomething(@PathVariable("path") String path) {...
```